# EditText value is reversed

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I've got an odd one. I'm trying to format some text while the user types into an EditText field. I am using the TextWatcher and responding to afterTextChanged event (code below). What is odd is after the first time this logic runs the text starts to become reversed. It seems that the Editable object contains the string backwards. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
_textWatcher = new TextWatcher()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
                    {
                        Editable e = textView.getText();
                        String text = e.toString();

                        logger.d("[FormListAdapter][addTextChangedListener] Format Text: " + text);

                        Number numVal = FormFieldBusiness.ConvertStringToNumber(text, formField.GetFormFieldType());
                        String fText = FormFieldBusiness.GetFormattedValue(numVal, formField.GetFormFieldType());

                        editText.removeTextChangedListener(_textWatcher);
                        textView.setText(text);
                        editText.addTextChangedListener(_textWatcher);
                    }
                };

                editText.addTextChangedListener(_textWatcher);
```

*** UPDATE ***

In an attempt to help anyone out there who's looking at this here is my XML layout file.

As I mentioned before the text is correct until after the first the time setText method is called. After that the Editable object is reversed.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp">

    <!-- Top Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:id="@+id/TopLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Headling Rent (pa)"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            style="@style/KelFormListItemLabel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:background="@color/formListItemValueBackgroundColor">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/CurrencyIconView"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_currency_pound"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ValueTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="20,000"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                style="@style/KelFormListItemValue"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:id="@+id/BottomLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TopLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BottomTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Headling Rent (pa)"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            style="@style/KelFormListItemLabel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:background="@color/formListItemValueBackgroundColor">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/BottomCurrencyIconView"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_currency_pound"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/BottomValueTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="20,000"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                style="@style/KelFormListItemValue"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why would someone down vote a question without posting a comment explaining the down vote? I just need to get some help figuring out why the text is being reversed. I posted all code that is relevant, so not sure why I was down voted.

Comment: upvoting to even things up. Can you run us through the things happening in afterTextChanged? From reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), I would think that any alteration you want to apply to the text should be done in onTextChanged instead of after.

Comment: All my logic in the afterTextChanged event does is convert the string into a number, then format it based on the type of field (E.g. integer, percent, currency, ect..) and then sets the formatted string to the EditText view. I have checked and my conversion logic isn't what flips the text. It goes into the setText in the correct order, and is reversed when the afterTextChanged event is called again. I have tried this also in the onTextChanged event and had the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are setting the text in the EditText field (even though you have removed the listener) you are listening for. this is causing the cursor to move to the beginning of the line, therefore making it type backwards

try changing from a TextWatcher to TextView.OnEditorActionListener and listen for the action key set on the EditText so when they hit the action key, it does your desired functionality.

add

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

to your button xml and assign it with

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener editingActionListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            //do stuff where you set the text here
        }
        return true;
    }
};
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(editingActionListener);
```

alternatively, you can use OnFocusChangeListener

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (v.getClass().equals(EditText.class)) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                //do your stuff here
            }
        }
    }
};
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener);
```

Comment: I had already fixed this issue, and not sure exactly what I did, but you're response makes sense:)

Comment: @miken.mkndev It would be a big help to the community if you try to look back on how you solved this, and post it as an answer. You can accept your own answer, plus you'll gain my upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply move the cursor to the correct position in your TextWatcher after setting the EditText content:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
{
    ...
    int position = editText.getSelectionStart();
    editText.setText(text);
    editText.setSelection(position);
    ...
}
```